# Is there a way to leverage the google voice recognition library?

Tags: android

Android has a really marvelous voice recognition feature built into google translate.  As far as I can tell, this is the only app that offers you the ability to speak in a foreign language, and have the app transcribe what you said (and subsequently translate it to another language).

I'm curious if anyone knows how one might leverage the voice recognition lib and utilize it for things other than translation. Specifically, I want to be able to dictate text for email. I googled around a bit, but was unable to find anything. Curious if this functionality is exposed to the wider developer community (like most everything else under the Google roof).

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is as close an answer as I'm going to find.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS